# What's difference?

Tags: php, methods, ampersand

Can someone explain what's the difference between `methodA` and `methodB` (with "&" sign) in PHP?

```
<?php
class X{
    public static function methodA(){return....;}

    public static function &methodB(){return....;}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `&` before the functions' name means it will return a reference instead of copying the return value back to the caller. You can find all the gritty details in [the documentation](http://php.net/references.return).